# Porque me sale este error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

[image: Codigo]

Me sale este error y no se como corregirlo : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Por favor, coloca el código y otros datos relevantes (mensajes de error, etc) **como texto**. Las imágenes no se pueden copiar/pegar y hacen mas difícil que nadie pueda ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: El uso que haces del constructor no es adecuado. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente no puedes declarar un arreglo así, puedas revisar [aquí](https://tutobasico.com/multidimensionales-javascript/) las maneras de declarar un arreglo multidimensional. Y como dijo @Trauma, si no usas texto, es muy difícil ayudarte. En cuanto a la pregunta, te está mostrando ese error porque tienes que declarar el arreglo antes de popularlo, tanto para la dimensión exterior como para la dimensión exterior.
Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
let individuos=7;
let cromosomas=6;
let generaciones=3;
let poblacion= new Array(cromosomas)
for (let i=0;i<cromosomas;i++){
  poblacion[i]=new Array(individuos)
  for (let j=0;j<individuos;j++){
    poblacion[i][j]=Math.round(Math.random())
    }
}
console.log(poblacion)
```

Comment: Estoy intentando ayudar, si saben la razón del voto en contra de mi respuesta, por favor diganmela para editar o eliminar la respuesta.

Comment: Podrias por favor escribir como seria la manera correcta?

Comment: @juniorguillermoalcarrazmont ya edité mi respuesta para que sea más clara. Espero te sirva.

Comment: @Trauma Ok, el OP muestra el código, pero es verdad que lo muestra mal, como ya se lo hicimos notar. También es verdad que no escuchó cuando le pedimos que lo muestre en texto. Gracias por el comentario, ahora que entiendo que no se debe contestar una pregunta así no vuelvo a hacerlo.

Comment: @DanielCarrera Creo que eres el primero que lo entiende a la primera sin *montar un pollo* ni tirarse de los pelos. Ok, retiro mi voto.